# How to "deploy" a server so that it can be reached over the internet?

Tags: java, android

I recently developed an Android application with which the Android device can communicate with another Android device running the application.
The communication works over sockets, therefore I developed a server which i run on my computer.

Here is my problem:

The communication between the devices over the Server running on my PC works fine, as long as all devices as well as the PC are in the same LAN (connected over the same Router for example).

Now I want to get the server online, so that the Android devices can connect to the "online" server and communicate with each other over the server from anywhere.

I simply have no idea of how to get the server online and running. How can I do that?

The main issue is, that I know about Client/Server communication locally, but have no experience in the "online" sector.

Comment: For production, you need rent services of some hoster which has public IPs. For testing purposes, just buy public IP from your current ISP.

Comment: I'd strongly, really strongly suggest you hire someone who **knows** how to do that right. Otherwise you might get hacked pretty quickly

Comment: @VictorSorokin You probably don't even need that. A good enough wireless router can register your IP with DynDNS or similar services, and keep this information up-to-date. (If you really want to host on your own hardware. Good Enough hosting is cheap enough though, although you can't use custom server software in that case.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is more a network problem than a programming one. Your server open a socket and therefore is available to anyone able to reach that socket.

You have to do a redirection on your router. The problem is that your machine doesn't have a public IP, only your router has one. So when your router receive a packet on port 21 for example, it doesn't know what to do with it. You have to configure it to say "the port 21 has to redirected to the local IP XXX"

Also the public IP of your modem/router can change, depending on your ISP. If your have a fixed IP, it won't change, otherwise you will have to install a software like dyndns to have a domain name associated with your IP.

Comment: It would help to be on a static IP as well

Comment: Ok, thank you.
Would it be possible to for example get the server online by using a free webhoster or anything like that? What would I have to consider when I'd do that?

Comment: A web hoster won't let you open a random port. A better practice is to develop a web service, accessible from the port 80. Also in the javaworld it is really hard to find something free to host your app, especially for your needs

Comment: U mean like developing a webservice for example with JAX-WS that implements the server?

Comment: For example yes. Developping using standards helps a lot when you are looking for a compatible web hoster

Comment: So that means it would be possible to "deploy" that webservice at a webhoster, and it can then be reached over the internet?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda Pretty much. To a web host, a web service implementation (like JAX-WS) is like any other web application. That said, Java might not be the best choice for the server part - it's not a very commonly supported technology when it comes to shared (read: cheap) hosting.